# Connected properly, but not working - CSS toggle

Tags: css

I am working on making a side navbar that resizes content once pulled out.

My script that changes classes isn't interacting properly with my css. I have confirmed that my script toggle does change the class, but despite all of my css working, once the class is added the css update doesn't take place. Do you know why?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title>Visualisation</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div id="wrapper"></div>
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Businesses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-lg-12'>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="menu-toggle">Toggle</a>
                <h1>Sidebar</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque in laudantium quas qui omnis aliquam. Est ipsam, quos omnis provident tenetur sunt laudantium alias libero, facere distinctio consectetur, cumque error.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click( function (e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed")
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    #wrapper.menuDisplayed #sidebar-wrapper{
    width: 10vw;
}

#wrapper.menuDisplayed #page-content-wrapper{
    padding-left: 10vw;
}
```

Comment: Neither #page-content-wrapper nor #sidebar-wrapper are descendants of #wrapper, so your html seems wrong. I'm guessing that the wrapper should wrap the rest, right?

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thankyou! :)